Issues with having a swiss tournaments that mixes matches rounds and game rounds
Definition:

A match round is when the paired players pay two games against each other, with opposite colours.
A game round is a round played as normal swiss round.

Say 11 (or any number that is a little over 10, but not large enough for a worthwhile 9 round swiss) turn up for a chess tournament that have 9 rounds timetabled, could it be played as a swiss tournament with the 1st round being normal games, then 4 rounds of matches?
What issues/problems are likely to result?  Will chess rating organisations have an issue with it?
See also Minimum number of players for 9 round Swiss tournament?
